# Why $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_q} H^0(X,D)^\sigma = \dim_{\mathbb{F}}H^0(X,D)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, zeta-functions, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I am trying to prove Theorem 11.3.7 (no proof or reference is left in the text) of [Edixhoven and Taelman lectures](http://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Eedixhovensj/teaching/2010-2011/AG-mastermath/ag.pdf) on Algebraic Geometry. The main goal of these lectures is to introduce algebraic geometry by proving Weil's conjectures for curves.

Here's some context: Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the field with $q$ elements and let $\mathbb{F}_q \to \mathbb{F}$ be an algebraic closure. Let $X$ be a smooth irreducible projective curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$, which for us means that $X$ is an irreducible smooth algebraic set in some $\mathbb{P}^m(\mathbb{F})$ of dimension 1 defined by some homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_q[x_0,\dots,x_m]$. Then the theorem asserts that for any divisor $D$ on $X$

> $$ \dim_{\mathbb{F}_q} H^0(X,D)^\sigma = \dim_{\mathbb{F}}H^0(X,D). $$

where
$$ H^0(X,D) = \lbrace f \in K(X) : f=0 \text{ or } \operatorname{div}(f)+D \geq 0\rbrace $$
and
$$ H^0(X,D)^\sigma  = \lbrace f \in K(X) : f\text{ has coefficients in } \mathbb{F}_q \rbrace
\cap H^0(X,D).$$

Is this trivial? Am I missing something? I am not very familiar with the language of schemes or cohomology. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd probably try and prove this first in the case when $D$ is fined over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and try to show that $H^0(X,D)^\sigma\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_q}\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}=H^0(X,D)$ which seems like it could just be from flat base change.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexYoucis; in these notes we define a divisor as an element of the free abelian group generated by the points of X. What is a flat base change?

Comment: If you write `\text{dim}` instead of `\dim` then instead of $2\dim(X)$ you'll see $2\text{dim}(X)$ and the difference in space to the right of "dim" between $2\dim(X)$ and $2\dim X$ will not be there unless it's added manually. Similarly with `\operatorname{div}` versus \text{div}. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you very much for your recommendation

Comment: @AlexYoucis I dont see why given $a \in \mathbb{F}$ there exists a $k$ such that $a^{q^k}$ is in $\mathbb{F}_q$

Comment: @JavierLinares My apologies! I wrote something dumb without thinking--it is late here in my defence :) I still think the general strategy I wrote works. I'll think on it and maybe answer tomorrow. Sorry again! Best of luck.

Comment: @JavierLinares One has an action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{F}/\mathbb{F}_q)$ on $K(X)$. (which I assume means rational functions over $\mathbb{F}$) If you assume that your $D$ is a divisor on $X$, which I assume means that $D$ consists of $\mathbb{F}_q$-points, then it's clear that your $H^0(X,D)$ is $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{F}/\mathbb{F}_q)$-stable subspace of $K(X)$. Then, you can apply something like Proposition 16.7 of this: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG16.pdf (look at its proof to see what the $W_0$ is, it's just $W\cap V$).